A doubt on understanding the ECI frame
I am currently studying the book Space Flight Dynamics by Craig A. Kluever. In the book, it is given as follows.


Figure 3.2 shows the geocentric-equatorial coordinate system for Earth-orbiting satellites.
The Earth’s equatorial plane is the fundamental $X–Y$ plane where the $+X$ axis points
in the vernal equinox direction (i.e., the same direction as the $+X_H$ axis in the heliocentric-ecliptic system). The $+Z$ axis is along the direction of the North Pole. The
geocentric-equatorial system is often called the Earth-centered INERTIAL (ECI) frame.
We will use unit vectors $IJK$ to designate the directions of the $XYZ$ axes as shown in
Figure 3.2. It is important for the reader to remember that the ECI system, while it moves with the Earth’s center, does not rotate.

My thoughts:
The ECI system does not rotate about any axis as told by the author as $+X$ axis is pointing towards the vernal equinox direction and I fully agree with that. We know that earth rotates around the sun. If the center of the system is earth, then the frame also moves along with the earth.
Question:
How is this frame i.e., ECI (Earth-centered INERTIAL) frame an INERTIAL frame as the rotation of the frame around the sun will give it a non-zero acceleration making it NON-INERTIAL ?
Please explain this to me and help me understand. Reference videos, if available, would be of great help.
Thank you.

FWIW, at 1 AU, the acceleration due to the Sun is ~0.00593 m/s^2. Also, the Earth is revolving around the Earth-Moon barycentre.

These are different, but you might find some answers helpful: How can Earth-Centered Inertial (ECI) coordinates be properly called "inertial" if the Earth's orbit is always accelerating towards the Sun? and maybe Are ECI and ECEF both frames and/or coordinate systems? Is there a difference? and What (the heck) are "space-fixed coordinates" as described in Apollo mission trajectory analyses?

Everything in the ECI frame will experience the relativistic effects the same.  So you only need to account for them when converting between reference frames.

It's not really inertial.  However, for some purposes, it's close enough to inertial to get away with pretending it is.  Also note, this definition of ECI is not the only one!  There are several different versions, which vary in what errors they assume are small enough to ignore.  The more precise your data becomes, the more you have to care about complicated non-inertial aspects that are glossed over in simpler definitions, such as this one.

This question is similar to: How can Earth-Centered Inertial (ECI) coordinates be properly called "inertial" if the Earth's orbit is always accelerating towards the Sun?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The key assumption is "...system for Earth-orbiting satellites...". For an interplanetary spacecraft, one would probably have to use another frame which is more inertial than ECI.

@uhoh DH's answer is 3 hours after Ryan C's comment. And also, the question shouldn't have been answered if its a dupe.

@Starship Thanks for that. You can complain to DH directly about his answer post, but in my experience DH usually gets it right. About the timing, I'll adjust some words and repost the comment. I generally exist out of time; working in the linear time world is challenging for me.

Hi @RyanC - DH has just posted a direct answer to the OP's question as asked, which I think works better than other answers to the other question. In this case I think answer prevention and direction of future readers to the other question is now not the best outcome, so I'd vote to keep open, or at least not block answers until the dust settles.

@uhoh  the answer to the question I suggested is a duplicate was also written by David Hammen.  :)  Since he apparently wanted to write another one, I have no objection to keeping both.


How is this frame i.e., ECI (Earth-centered INERTIAL) frame an INERTIAL frame as the rotation of the frame around the sun will give it a non-zero acceleration making it NON-INERTIAL?

You are correct; a better name would be Earth-centered non-rotating. However, everyone calls frames such as the one described in your text "Earth-centered inertial" (or Mars-centered inertial in the case of a vehicle orbiting Mars, etc.). What this means is that to obtain a good description of a body's trajectory is that one needs to account for difference between the body's acceleration and the Earth's acceleration toward the Sun (and of course toward other massive solar system bodies).
For some reason, these are called "third body effects" as opposed to tidal effects. To physicists, those third body effects are definitely called tidal effects. To aerospace engineers, tidal effects are something totally different. The Moon causes tides not only in the oceans but also in the Earth itself. That in turn subtly changes the Earth's gravity. So we're stuck with the names "planet-centered inertial" and "third body effects". That said, a rose by any other name smells just as sweet.
As an aside the frame as described in your textbook is rotating. The Earth undergoes precession, nutation, and polar motion. One has to either pick an epoch date to decide the frame's orientation forever (this is what the FK5 and GCRF do; they use the J2000 epoch pointing of the Earth's rotation axis and equatorial plane). Two other widely used choices are mean of date and true of date. Mean of date ignores nutation and polar motion; true of date incorporates notation and sometimes even polar motion. Your textbook appears to be describing mean of date ECI or true of date ECI.
